# Remove all vertices connected to one or less edges?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools

Using the boolean operator a lot creates a lot of junk vertices and edges that make it really difficult to clean up a model so my question is: is there a way to delete all vertices connected to one or less edges?

Comment: Nope, that selected valid vertices connected to two or more edges.

Comment: Try using *Amount of connecting edges* instead.

Comment: none of the shift+g options are effective in selecting the correct vertices.

Comment: You should post some pictures, examples, or .blend file else its unclear what you actually want.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *> Amount of Connecting edges* works for me.

You will have to select a vertex with no connecting edges and a vertex with one connecting edge in order to select all vertices with one or fewer connecting edges at once:

[image]

There are also *Greater than* and *Less than* options in the *Redo panel* (<kbd>F6</kbd>).

Comment: The issue wouldn't be demonstrated well with an image as the vertices aren't hanging out in the open like that.  Try taking a bunch of cylinders and having them overlap at different angles against a cube including with 2-4 other cylinders from the group (say 12+ overlapping cylinders with 120 in the vertices section - or a similar numbers of icospheres with 4-6 subdivisions) then apply a boolean difference to the cube for each of them.  When you go into edit mode for the cube afterward and click around you'll see lots of hanging vertices where the edges intersected.

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but I guess the bigger issue here is that after so many difference operations the difference operator can no longer work (sending models to shapeways via export to dae and they have to be pretty clean without hanging vertices or bad normals on faces or they end up failing the tests before printing).  I've gotten into the habit of manually taking the intersections of each edge but suffice to say that's very time-consuming and for models with multiple overlapping shells and 20+ overlapping difference operations it is next to impossible even in wireframe mode.