# Limited Dissolve leaves unused Vertices

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Sometimes In order to get the effect I want I'll subdivide more than I need, then use Limited Dissolve to remove unused areas.

I just noticed that it sometimes (or maybe always?) leaves the separate edges/verts that were there from the original subdivision.

Is there a way to prevent this or clean up verts that do nothing?

Thanks!

[image: Dissolved face]

[image: Undissolved Edges/Verts]

Comment: Like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26162/599)?

Comment: @gandalf3 I don't think so, the wording there is "delete all vertices connected to one or less edges" but I think my issue would be better described as "one vertex connected to exactly 2 edges that are in alignment". I'll add a picture to the question for clarity.

Comment: Ah, nice. Didn't turn up on my limited dissolve searches.Edit: I had tried this manually, but whenever I use "Dissolve Vert" I just get an error, says it couldn't do it. The selection method is handy though.

Comment: Hmm, tried that solution on just 2 of the problem verts and it removes the edges too? Updating from 2.7 to latest just in case.

Comment: Same thing happens in 2.73a, but if I select the edges that run between 2 different problem verts and use edge dissolve that seems to work. Thanks